# AEM HTL Number formatting to 2 digits

Tags: aem, sightly

Is there a number formatter in HTL that can format number to 2 digits. I want

```
<h2>${ '#' @ format=3}</h2>
```

to render 03 instead of 3.

Is there a HTL way of doing this without taking help from Sling Model?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A regular Java number format pattern can be used: `${"00" @ format=3}`

Comment: True. Was overthinking for such simple fix. Thanks.